# Javascript traversing DOM upwards

Tags: javascript, dom

In jQuery to traverse DOM several steps upward instead of

```
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().click();
```

I can write short version:

```
 $(this).parent(5).click();
```

So, I want to know, if there's a way to shorten code instead of spamming '.parentNode'?

Comment: I personally avoid `parent()` except for rare occasions.  I strongly prefer [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) - finds the closest element that matches the selector: `$(this).closest('div.some-class');`....

Comment: have you tried using a loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using parentNode multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151440/using-parentnode-multiple-times)

Comment: The same way jQuery does it: write a function that loops `.parentNode` n times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather trivial:

```js
function parent (element, n = 1) {
  let {parentNode} = element;
  for (let i = 1; parentNode && i < n; i++) {
    ({parentNode} = parentNode);
  }
  return parentNode;
}

const span = document.querySelector('span');
const directParent = parent(span);                  // direct parent node
const greatGreatGreatGrandParent = parent(span, 5); // parent node 5 times
console.log(directParent.getAttribute('data-foo'));                // baz
console.log(greatGreatGreatGrandParent.getAttribute('data-foo')); // bar
```

```html
<div data-foo="bar">
  <div>
    <div>
       <div>
         <div data-foo="baz">
          <span>Hello, World!</span>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I check for `parentNode` because it might be `null`. In that case, I break the loop and return `null`, because continuing the loop would result in an error:

```
({parentNode} = null); // TypeError: can't convert null to object
```

The parentheses are necessary to indicate that the opening `{` doesn't start a block, but a destructuring assignment:

```
{parentNode} = parentNode; // SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='
```

#### Edit:

I must admit that my solution is rather condensed and uses some new JavaScript features to make it even more succinct.

#### What does `let {parentNode} = element;` mean?

[Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) lets you read properties from an object in a more succinct way:

```
let {parentNode} = element;
```

is equivalent to:

```
let parentNode = element.parentNode;
```

As explained above,

```
({parentNode} = parentNode);
```

is equivalent to:

```
parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
```

#### What does `parentNode && i < n` exactly?

Every `for`-loop has a condition. If this condition is true, the loop is continued. If the condition is false, it breaks out of the loop.

I could write:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

That would run the loop `n - 1` iterations. After the last iteration, `i` is equal to `n`, so the condition evaluates to `false` and it stops, which is fine.

`parentNode && i < n` extends this condition. It not only checks whether `i` is less than `n`, but it also checks if `parentNode` contains a truthy value. If `parentNode` is `null` (which might happen is an element has no parent node), the loop will break, because it can't read the property `parentNode` of null.

---

I hope you understand the explanations with the following function which is equivalent to the original one:

```js
function parent (element, times) {
  var n; // how many times 'parentNode'?
  if (times) {
    n = times;
  } else {
    n = 1;
  }
  var elementToReturn = element.parentNode;
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (elementToReturn === null) {
      break;
    } else {
      elementToReturn = elementToReturn.parentNode;
    }
  }
  return elementToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Wow, can you briefly explain the code, please? why are you checking for `parent` in the `for` loop and why `({parentNode} = parentNode)`? I read about the object/array destructuring but I can't understand that.

Comment: The `parent` was a typo. I should be `parentNode`.

Comment: What `parentNode && i < n` does exactly?

Comment: And `let {parentNode} = element;` as well. And difference between `parentNode` and `{parentNode}`. Object destructuring is above me for now..

Comment: Okay, so far so good. I've managed to solve issue that was bugging me (my code is nice and short now), thus thanks for that. Do you know, though, how to chain that function? I've tried `this.parent(5).style.display = 'none;'`, and it ignored me.

Comment: You have to call it as `parent(this, 5).style.display = ...`. If you want to be able to call it as `this.parent(...)`, you have to assign it to `HTMLElement.prototype` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670361/how-to-add-my-own-methods-to-htmlelement-object)). But I recommend you don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The sorcerer's one-liner...
It's the same as @petermader's only shorter. I guess there's less of a need to be super explicit here, as this would probably be just an imported utility function, and it's still more reliable than a for loop.

```
const getParentElement = ({ parentNode }, n = 1) =>
  Array.from({ length: n - 1 }, () => ({ parentNode } = parentNode)) && parentNode
```